# Inserting into SQLite table only chosen values with QSql

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I want to insert some values into an SQLite table.

The query is:

```
insert into TableName (field1,field2,field3) values (field1val, field2val, field3val)
```

Let's say the table has 20 fields. I want to choose which field should be inserted depending on this value which is user input. The rest of fields should have no value.

My current solution is:

```
QString valuesToInsertFieldNames("(");
QString valuesToInsert("(");
if(field1val != -1)
{
    valuesToInsertFieldNames+= "field1";
    valuesToInsert += QString("%1 ").arg(field1val);
}
if(field2val != -1)
{
    valuesToInsertFieldNames+= "field2";
    valuesToInsert += QString("%1").arg(field2val);
}
...
valuesToInsertFieldNames+= ")";
valuesToInsert += ")";
query.exec(QString("insert into TableName " + valuesToInsertFieldNames + 
                   "values" + valuesToInsert)
```

Is there some better way of doing it? Maybe some QSql functionality?

Comment: is the `else if` intended? you need to add field2 only if you did not add field1? So you don't know in advance how many, and which fields are going to be inserted?

Comment: No `else if` was not intended. Yes i don't now how many and which fields.

Comment: Ok, one more question, what data type are the values?

Comment: Is not setting that column actually different from setting it to NULL? Because if you can do the later, preparing the statement once and inserting all rows with it is orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hold the names and values in a map, and construct the query in a cycle:

```
//You hold the field names and the corresponding values here.
//The map's key is the field name, the map's value is the value. 
QVariantMap pairs;
//this will hold the values to compare with to decide whether to print the value
//or not
QVariantList compareWithMe;

QString fieldNames;
QString fieldValues;

int count = 0;
QVariantMap::iterator it = pairs.begin();
for( it; it != pairs.end(); it++ )
{
    if( it.value().toInt() == compareWithMe[count] )
    {
        count++;
        continue;
    }
    fieldNames.append( it.key() );
    fieldValues.append( it.value().toString() );
    //fieldValues.append( QString("%1").arg(it.value()) ); if you like it this way. 
    count++;
}

//Note that I've placed the opening and closing braces here, 
//saving you two lines of code:
//fieldNames.append(")");
//fieldValues.append(")");
query.exec(QString(
           "INSERT INTO TableName (" 
           + fieldNames 
           + ") VALUES (" 
           + fieldValues 
           + ")"
           ));
```

Comment: I agree, this way the code is cleaner and more readable. Also it is easier to add new fields when necessary.

Comment: Very nice solution. But as I said values are different data types. So `it.value().toInt() == -1 ` won't work for me.

Comment: Sorry it was not precise I mean datatypes varies so converting value to int won't work.

Comment: -1: Anyone who suggests that string formatting might ever be appropriate for generating SQL should be banned from doing anything with databases. Always use `QSqlQuery::bindValue`.

Comment: (and note, that QSqlQuery::bindValue takes a QVariant, so no converting to int issue)